# Nested Type Hinting Differing Results

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I've been trying to tighten up a few classes of code with type hinting.  I'm struggling with a nesting problem.  The parameter of a function of interest is an iterable container of objects with known types.  I'm having trouble getting my IDE to recognize the inner types (which is a nice convenience.)

I'm using python 3.9 on PyCharm, but I'm getting similar auto-complete results in Ipython.

When using the `Iterable` class out of `typing` module, the IDE cannot "see through" to the inner types.  Similarly for `Collection`.  But it can when using either `list` or `tuple` on the outer container.

Is this an IDE issue or is there another way to package this?  It would be nice to be able to send this function any type of iterable, rather than hard code it...

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Iterable

Data_collection = Iterable[tuple[datetime, str]]
Data_list = list[tuple[datetime, str]]

def foo(bar: Data_collection):
    bar[1][0].    # no type-hint on inner obj

def foo2(bar: Data_list):
    bar[1][0].    # good type-hint on inner obj
```

Gets me (PyCharm) results like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I never noticed that this bothered me until you asked the question. Nice.

Comment: This is purely an IDE issue, but consider this: an `Iterable` doesn't necessarily support indexing, so `bar[1]` may not even be valid. The only thing `Iterable` promises is an `__iter__` method. If you want something that can be indexed, you want `Sequence`.

Comment: Ahh, @chepner.  Yeah, the indexing is not important in this case, and I think my incorrect use of indexing tubed this.  When I iterate through the `iterable` in proper fashion, PyCharm works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong abstract base class. `Iterable` only promises/requires `__iter__` to be implemented, not `__getitem__`. Statically speaking, `bar[1]` isn't guaranteed to be defined.

To specify any type that supports indexing, use `Sequence` instead.

```
from typing import Sequence


Data_collection = Sequence[tuple[datetime, str]]
```

Now, regardless of the runtime type of `bar`, your IDE can assume that `bar.__getitem__` is defined and returns a `tuple`. (Whether your specific IDE *does* make that assumption depends on the IDE, not your code.)

Comment: Good catch.  As noted above, when I get my head out of my backside and use an iterator (which is fine for this) it works as hoped.  And if I type with `Sequence` and index it works too!  Good catch